# is $f(t)=(1+t^2)\left(\operatorname{cos(t)},\operatorname{sin(t)},1\right)$ a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, trigonometry, differential-topology

How can i show that the curve $f:\mathbb{(-\pi,2\pi)}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
\begin{equation}
f(t)=(1+t^2)\left(\operatorname{cos(t)},\operatorname{sin(t)},1\right)
\end{equation}
is injective ? Does a general way to show it exist for general curves?
I can see that de diferential is injective but i can't view that f is injective.

Comment: If you know that the image of an embedding is a submanifold, all that it remains to ask is if the function $f$ is continuous...

Comment: but f isn't a embedding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|f(t)|=\sqrt{2}(1+t^2)$, so for $f(t)=f(s)$ we need
\begin{align*}
1+t^2&=1+s^2,\\
(\cos t,\sin t, 1)&=(\cos s,\sin s, 1).
\end{align*}
The first equation holds iff
$$
s=\pm t,
$$
and the second holds iff
$$
s=t + 2k\pi,\quad k\in {\mathbb Z}.
$$

But the domain is $(-\pi,2\pi)$,  so $s=-t$ iff $s, t\in (-\pi,\pi)$, which is the only symmetric part for negation.

Then $s=t + 2k\pi$ means $k$ can only be 0, since for $s,t\in (-\pi,\pi)$, $|s-t|<2\pi$.

Therefore $s=t$ is the only solution.